# We are using golang with gin/gonic for our backend server. A service sets a cookie 'token' on HTTP Redirect which works on localhost but not on Prod

Tags: go, saml, http-redirect, setcookie, go-gin

We have implemented crewjam/saml (https://github.com/crewjam/saml) for SSO as a Service Provider which uses Set-Cookie on HTTP Redirect. On localhost, the cookie is setting fine on localhost but on production, it is not able to set the cookie. This cookie contains the session on success of SSO.

[image: Cookie Attributes]

Everything was working fine, until a few weeks back.

I am attaching the images of requests for reference that starts with the following calls:

1. /saml/acs: Validates assertion and responds with HTTP Redirect [/query/saml/login?email=akshaj@conduct-sso-domain.internal] + Set-Cookie
   [image]
2. /query/saml/login?email=akshaj@conduct-sso-domain.internal: Contains the cookie and responds with another HTTP Redirect
   [image]

In localhost, the cookie is being stored but production, not getting stored

I have tried the following:

1. Server - setting allowCredentails to true
2. Frontend - Disabling any CSP

We are using crewjam/saml as a library for implementing SSO, so configuring Set-Cookie is not an option as it is inbuilt.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).